# Batch deleting of Earth Engine assets

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have 100+ assets in Earth Engine that I want to delete at once. Unfortunately they're not in a specific folder, they're in the home folder. They all begin with '01_...' so I thought about using the [gee_asset_manager](https://samapriya.github.io/gee_asset_manager_addon/projects/move/) with a wildcard, e.g., `geeadd delete --id "users/me/01_*"` but it doesn't work -- looks like it needs the asset full path. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for this using python. While the same can be achieved in the code editor as javascript code, it will ask you for confirmation for each file through a dialog box, so it's not feasible for 100+ files.

First, define this function:

```py
def conditional_asset_rm(x, starts_with):
    """Deletes asset if starts with starts_with """
    id = x["id"]              # users/username/file  or projects/project-name/assets/file
    findex = 5 if id.startswith("users") else 3
    name = x["name"]          # projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/username/file or projects/project-name/assets/file
    f = name.split("/")[findex]  # file
    if (f.startswith(starts_with)):
        #ee.data.deleteAsset(id)
        return f"Deleted asset {id}"
    
    return 0
```

Note that there is a difference between "id" and "name" for the `users/username` (legacy) assets, as well as the start of the actual "file" name after "assets", thus you either check for the 3rd or 5th element after splitting with "/" depending if it is a legacy (user/me) or within a project.

Next, retrieve your asset list:

```py
#asset_list = ee.data.listAssets("projects/myproject/assets")["assets"]
# ^ the above if checking assets for a project 
# For user assets:
asset_list = ee.data.listAssets("users/me/")["assets"]
```

Finally, map or call the function for each asset using the condition that it starts with "01_":

```py
[conditional_asset_rm(x, "01_") for x in asset_list]
```

First do a dry run (`ee.data.deleteAsset` is commented) and if you are happy with the list of files that got printed ("Deleted asset X"), then you are good to go.

Another option would be to use the [command-line tool](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/command_line) to first print the list of assets to a text file, then edit it to just keep the ones you want to delete, and finally process it using a shell script to call the command-line tool to delete each one at a time.